# Can some one mention about number of commits in their resume under certain project

Tags: resume

Can someone mention in their resume that he has the highest number of commits in the project repo or is it too braggy?

If it is braggy and not the right thing to do than how should one tell of his overall contribution to the project, Like what other ways can one show that he has contributed a major chunk in some project.

Comment: Hi Aamir, welcome to The Workplace SE. I wanted to suggest that you add more details when asking questions on our site. We're not a traditional back-and-forth discussion forum, so we like questions to contain enough details about your situation to be answered right away. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can mention whatever you want in a resume, but talking about the number of commits is not going to necessarily be helpful. Contribution to a project does not necessarily correspond to number of commits.

For example, one person may write relatively small chunks of easy code, and commit each time they finish one. Another person may write large chunks of highly complex and important code, and write several parts before committing. The first person may have more commits but not make a bigger contribution to the project. As an extreme example, a person who every time they make a commit breaks the build, has to undo it, fix it and commit again has *three times* as many commits as another person who gets it right each time; you wouldn't say they were better than the other person though.

I recommend focussing on the functionality of the code you wrote. Write down what parts of the project you wrote, and what they contributed to the end result. it will be much better.

Comment: Also, I would add to focus on what problems I solved. Many managers want problem solvers, not just coders as some problems don't necessarily require more code but instead benefit from less code. ["If all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail." - Abraham Maslow](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_all_you_have_is_a_hammer,_everything_looks_like_a_nail)